# Pushing data to array does not work using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am trying to push a new element to an array and to my surprise it does not work. I have no idea what is wrong here. Below is the code:

```
buildContactsCollection(primaryContact: Card){
    if(primaryContact.phones === undefined){
      primaryContact.phones = []
    }

    let primaryPhone = this.formatPhoneNumber(primaryContact.mobileRawNumber, primaryContact.mobile)

    console.log("in build collection primary phone is", primaryPhone)
    if(primaryPhone !== undefined){

      console.log("before phones are:", primaryContact.phones)
      primaryContact.phones.push({
        "type" : "personal",
        "phoneType": "mobile",
        "extn": "",
        "rawNumber": primaryPhone
      })

      console.log("after pushing:", primaryContact)
    }
```

where the card object definition is:

```
export class Card {
private _mobile:string
private _mobileRawNumber:string
private _phones:Object[]

 get mobile():string{
        return this._mobile
    }

    set mobile(val:string){
        this._mobile = val
    }

 get mobileRawNumber():string{
        return this._mobileRawNumber
    }

    set mobileRawNumber(val:string){
        this._mobileRawNumber = val
    }

  get phones(): Object[]{
        if(this._phones === undefined)
            this._phones = []

        return this._phones
    }

    set phones(val:Object[]){
        this._phones = val
    }
```

The output on console however shows that it is not pushing a new object to phones array even when primaryPhone is a non undefined and non blank value.

Comment: This code seems to work as you expect. Please make sure to post a reproducible example of the error.

Comment: "Does not work" - how? Make sure `primaryPhone` is not `undefined`

Comment: primaryPhone is not undefined

Comment: What is the error that you're getting (in the console for example)?

Answer (score 0):

In your class `Card`, the private attribute is `_phones`, not `phones`.

Same applies for the other private attributes.

### New code to adapt:

```js
buildContactsCollection(primaryContact: Card) {
  
    if (primaryContact._phones === undefined){
      primaryContact._phones = []
    }

    let primaryPhone = this.formatPhoneNumber(primaryContact._mobileRawNumber, primaryContact._mobile)

    console.log("in build collection primary phone is", primaryPhone)
    if(primaryPhone !== undefined){

      console.log("before phones are:", primaryContact._phones)
      primaryContact._phones.push({
        "type" : "personal",
        "phoneType": "mobile",
        "extn": "",
        "rawNumber": primaryPhone
      })

      console.log("after pushing:", primaryContact)
    }
}
```